# ID vs Var with find function

Tags: jquery

which is faster

```
 <div class="box"><div id="inside"></div></div>

 jquery 

  var div_obox = $('.box');
  var div_Ibox = div_obox.find("#inside") or var div_Ibox = $("#inside");
```

Just eager to know which is faster I know using ID is the fastest but however even using variable is much faster I guess.

I was expecting as it has already found `.box` element in the first statement and so its easy for the browser to find `#inside` element, using `find` function. As we are specifying that, it exists inside the `.box` and if i use `id` here, I guess it need to start the searching process from the start again. Let me know Id versus var with find function. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you run a test on jsPerf.com and find out?

Comment: jsperf Sorry i have no idea about it. let me see it and Thanks @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#inside")` is faster than `div_obox.find("#inside")` and than `$('.box > #inside')` because jQuery, in the first case, may and do use `document.getElementById` and all browsers maintain a direct map between the id and the related elements.

From the source code :

```
    // Shortcuts
    if ( (match = rquickExpr.exec( selector )) ) {
        // Speed-up: Sizzle("#ID")
        if ( (m = match[1]) ) {
            if ( nodeType === 9 ) {
                elem = context.getElementById( m );
```

Never add anything to a `'#id'` selector if there is no logical reason (i.e. checking the elements exists in a specific part of the DOM).

Answer (score 1):

I would just run some tests...

But I believe all elements are indexed by their id's on the page so `$('#inside')` or `$('.box > #inside')` would be much faster than `$('.box').find('#inside')`

Answer (score 1):

I trust A direct *ID*  i.e  `$("#inside")` will always be the **fastest**, as everything on `DOM` indexed by unique ID .